# Include all files in Eclipse c++ index

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am having some troubles using eclipse to navigate a massive project. The problem I am attempting to facilitate is searching for where functions are defined, where classes are defined, and following other references throughout the code.

I was previously using grep to search everything, and that was no a very good solution as it took about 2 minutes for every search.

Is there a way to add all files to my Eclipse index?

> the file 'soc-core.c' is currently not part of the index.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate. I believe I have selected the appropriate options. Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be hitting a limit that prevents indexing from finishing.  Here are some things to try.

- Increase the memory available to eclipse.  In your eclipse.ini file, set the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` values to bigger numbers.  I'm using `-Xms512m -Xmx2048m` but you may need even bigger.
- Increase the "Cache limits" fields at the bottom of the Indexer preference page.
- Start eclipse and let it sit for a while.  It should show you "C/C++ Indexer: (X%) progress bar in the lower right corner.  Give it time to get to 100%.
- You might try rebuilding the index.  Menu->Project->C/C++ ndex->Rebuild.
- In your project settings, you might need to add directories to C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes
- Get a newer version of eclipse-cpp. I had a version a long while back that never seemed to finish indexing--it would get stuck.  I'm now using eclipse-cpp-kepler-R and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

If you have large files in terms of LOC, you may be taken into scalable mode by eclipse where indexing didn't work for me. So. I changed the scalability settings to 50,000 lines. Now indexing is working large files too (<50k)